# How do I save my betta fish from dying because of a dirty tank?

Tags: aquarium, betta

I have a betta fish and I keep him in a gallon tank with a water filter. There has been algae growing in his tank but I thought it was normal and didn't pay mind to it. Today I see the water is cloudy and found my fish laying on the bottom of the tank- almost dead. I see he is still breathing and I saw him swim up for air once. But I am worried he is going to die. I moved him to a jar temporarily with 60% clean conditioned tap water and 40% his tank water. But I know I can't keep him in the jar for long. Help! I really don't want him to die he is barely 2 years old.

Comment: Any time I have seen cloudy water , it is from over feeding.

Answer (score 2):

1) Put him in something larger than a 1 gallon. I'm sure you've heard this before, but I promise it's true.

2) Add a snail - snails eat algae and will clear up your tank fast. Only do this if you actually use a larger tank.

3) If you haven't had the water in your tank for very long, the cloudy water could just be good bacteria forming.

4) Algae can also form because of overfeeding (decomposing food). I would reduce your feeding to once a day. A betta's stomach is only about as big as it's eye, so feed accordingly.

All of the above are from personal experience.

5) Since it's just a 1 gallon tank, I would replace a standard coffee cup worth of water every week with an equal amount conditioned water.

Comment: Can you rewrite this without the questions so it's more of a complete answer than an invitation to discussion? It's a great start, but could use more detail and fewer questions.

Comment: @AllisonC done!

Answer (score 0):

Keep a first aid kit. Pet stores often will not carry Betta fish medication, meaning that you will need to order it online. If you do this after your Betta fish gets sick it will likely be too late.

Prevent illness. Most Betta fish ailments are caused by improper feeding and cleaning. These will be examined in greater detail later.

Know how to recognize the first signs of illness. The most obvious way to tell that a Betta fish is sick is to observe whether or not it wants to eat. If it is not eating or appears unexcited at the sight of food, it is likely sick. Other signs of illness include a less vibrant color or strange discolorations.